# Convert use Date.parser() in groovy Extra minute

Tags: date, parsing, datetime, groovy

In my function exist two away to convert cellDateValue in Date, first use string (my problem is this one) and second use double.

```
if (cellDateValue ==~ /[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{4}/){
    return Date.parse('dd/mm/yyyy', cellDateValue)
} else {
    return cellDateValue ? DateUtil.getJavaDate(cellDateValue.toDouble()) : null
}
```

**Input:** `cellvalue` equals `01/01/2016`
**Output:** `2016-01-01T00:01:00.000-0200`
In output exist one minute more, create problem if compare other dates

**My solution:**
replace `Date.parse('dd/mm/yyyy', cellDateValue)`
to `Date.parse('dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm', cellDateValue + ' 00:00')`

That is a good away ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change:

```
'dd/mm/yyyy'
```

To

```
'dd/MM/yyyy'
```

You're parsing the second `01` into minutes, `MM` is for months

ie:

```
return Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', cellDateValue)
```